# Can't create the AndroidWebView cause of missing the org.chromium.webview_shell/.WebViewBrowserActivity activity class

Tags: typescript, webview, playwright

I know that WebView is an experimental feature of the Playwright but I'm trying to figure out how to work with it.
I copied the example from the official [documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-android) and after I had run that code, I caught the error:

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.chromium.webview_shell/.WebViewBrowserActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.chromium.webview_shell/org.chromium.webview_shell.WebViewBrowserActivity} does not exist.
```

The program finishes with the TimeOut error cause of missing that class
Has anyone worked with WebView yet? How can I solve this problem with missing org.chromium.webview_shell/org.chromium.webview_shell.WebViewBrowserActivity class?

This is my code:

```
const { _android: android } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  // Connect to the device.
  const [device] = await android.devices();
  console.log(`Model: ${device.model()}`);
  console.log(`Serial: ${device.serial()}`);

  let buffer = await device.shell('am force-stop org.chromium.webview_shell');
  buffer = await device.shell('am start org.chromium.webview_shell/.WebViewBrowserActivity');
  let result = buffer.toLocaleString();
  console.log("Start WebViewBrowserActivity" + result);
  // Get the WebView.
  const webview = await device.webView({ pkg: 'org.chromium.webview_shell' });

  // Fill the input box.
  await device.fill({
    res: 'org.chromium.webview_shell:id/url_field',
  }, 'github.com/microsoft/playwright');
  await device.press({
    res: 'org.chromium.webview_shell:id/url_field',
  }, 'Enter');

  // Work with WebView's page as usual.
  const page = await webview.page();
  await page.waitForNavigation({ url: /.*microsoft\/playwright.*/ });
  console.log(await page.title());

  // Close the device.
  await device.close();
})();
```

And this is the console output:

```
@MAC-556365 widgets_ts_automation % node tests/common/webview.spec.js
Model: sdk_gphone_x86_64
Serial: emulator-5554
Start WebViewBrowserActivityStarting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=org.chromium.webview_shell/.WebViewBrowserActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.chromium.webview_shell/org.chromium.webview_shell.WebViewBrowserActivity} does not exist.

node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

androidDevice.webView: Timeout 30000ms exceeded while waiting for event "webview"
    at /Users/oleksii.yefimenko/VSCode_projects/widgets_ts_automation/tests/common/webview.spec.js:47:32 {
  name: 'TimeoutError'
}

Node.js v20.8.0
```